# WPF change icon color created using canvas and path

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons

I have an icon created with canvas and path. I can reuse this icon, but how can I change the color of the icon from "outside" (i.e. from view)

```
<Canvas x:Key="MyIcon" Width="40.000" Height="23.889">
    <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Compound Path> -->
    <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 36.074,14.516 C 36.117,10.711 33.078,7.540 29.332,7.478 Z"/>

    <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Compound Path> -->
    <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 35.848,2.368 C 36.766,3.651 37.097,3.832 38.095,3.558 C 38.345,3.489 38.523,3.159 38.735,2.950 C 38.499,2.756 38.281,2.426 38.025,2.395  Z"/>

    <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Path> -->
    <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 35.307,14.487 C 35.268,17.908 32.499,20.618 29.098,20.563 C 25.615,20.506 22.916,17.747 22.947,14.274 Z"/>
</Canvas>
```

With this icon, it will always be white. What changes I can make so I will be able to change the color from xaml? For example now I show the icon like this:

`<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" />`

I'm assuming to change the color the syntax will look something like this:

`<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyIcon}" Color={StaticResource BlueBrush} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the Canvas into a Geometry resource by concatening the Data strings of the three Paths:

```
<Geometry x:Key="MyIcon">F1 M 36.074,14.516 C 36.117,10.711 33.078,7.540 29.332,7.478 Z M 35.848,2.368 C 36.766,3.651 37.097,3.832 38.095,3.558 C 38.345,3.489 38.523,3.159 38.735,2.950 C 38.499,2.756 38.281,2.426 38.025,2.395 Z M 35.307,14.487 C 35.268,17.908 32.499,20.618 29.098,20.563 C 25.615,20.506 22.916,17.747 22.947,14.274 Z</Geometry>
```

The use that resource with a single Path element instead of a ContentControl:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource MyIcon}" Fill="Blue"/>
```